# Power automate Tasks output not correct as an array is needed

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

Hi Wan't to save all my tasks from all planners of my site to an excel file. I'm trying to use power automate like this
[image]
[image]

when testing all recurring om Apply to each (current item) is failing all the time.
Error is The execution of template action 'Apply_to_each' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@items('Appliquer_à_chacun_2')' is of type 'Object'. The result must be a valid array.

What should I had as output for  to each steps?

Comment: You’ll need to explain all of the for each expressions you’ve entered that form the array to loop over AND supply the json from the payload that came into the trigger.